Using Piranha CMS
I want to add a blogging capability to the sites I produce for clients and I would like to use Piranha.  I've installed the Piranha templates and got a working project in Razor pages with some seeded data.  However, I can't figure out how to add in the existing landing page for the client site.  On start up, I'd like to be able to navigate to one or more Razor pages that I have written, and then move over to the Piranha blog via a menu option (and back again).  I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I can't figure it out, as Piranha seems to want to constrain the navigation to page types that are then edited via the block editor, (which is not sophisticated enough for my use).
If it helps, here's my current program.cs file
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Piranha;
using Piranha.AspNetCore.Identity.SQLite;
using Piranha.AttributeBuilder;
using Piranha.Data.EF.SQLite;
using Piranha.Manager.Editor;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.AddPiranha(options =>
{
    /**
     * This will enable automatic reload of .cshtml
     * without restarting the application. However since
     * this adds a slight overhead it should not be
     * enabled in production.
     */
    options.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation = true;

    options.UseCms();
    options.UseManager();

    options.UseFileStorage(naming: Piranha.Local.FileStorageNaming.UniqueFolderNames);
    options.UseImageSharp();
    options.UseTinyMCE();
    options.UseMemoryCache();

    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("piranha");
    options.UseEF<SQLiteDb>(db => db.UseSqlite(connectionString));
    options.UseIdentityWithSeed<IdentitySQLiteDb>(db => db.UseSqlite(connectionString));

    /**
     * Here you can configure the different permissions
     * that you want to use for securing content in the
     * application.
    options.UseSecurity(o =>
    {
        o.UsePermission("WebUser", "Web User");
    });
     */

    /**
     * Here you can specify the login url for the front end
     * application. This does not affect the login url of
     * the manager interface.
    options.LoginUrl = "login";
     */
});

var app = builder.Build();


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseRouting();


app.UsePiranha(options =>
{
    // Initialize Piranha
    App.Init(options.Api);

    // Build content types
    new ContentTypeBuilder(options.Api)
        .AddAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly)
        .Build()
        .DeleteOrphans();

    // Configure Tiny MCE
    EditorConfig.FromFile("editorconfig.json");

    options.UseManager();
    options.UseTinyMCE();
    options.UseIdentity();
});

app.Run();

